# Installing fonts in Elementary

Tags: fonts

I'm coming to Elementary from Zorin. In Zorin, I was able to put all my fonts in a .fonts folder in the home directory. However, that doesn't seem to work in Elementary. Any advice here?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install them. Check if Gnome Fonts are installed (normally is), then just click on font file and it will install.

Comment: Thanks! So is it safe to assume that there is no easy way to install multiple fonts at once? Each one would have to be installed separately?